# Eclipse won't save because i have used alt code characters?

Tags: java, eclipse, save

Im using javacc with eclipse and my task is to create my own programming language. I tried to use a few alt code to create musical notes and use that when creating a program based on that but eclipse gives me this error.

"Some character cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding.

It is possible to use alt codes or other language characters in eclipse?
Can i change the encoding of Cp1252? if so how?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project, choose `Properties`, in the Properties-Window choose `Resource` and under `Text file encoding` choose something like `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can change the encoding of a resource by rightclicking on the resource in the explorer view and selecting "Properties" from the context menu (or mark the resource and press Alt + Return). Then navigate to "Resource" where you can change the resource's encoding.

If "Default" is inherited you'd have to look for the encoding of the folders/packages or the project.